# VBA Array of Dates Transposes as Strings

Tags: excel, vba

I have an array of dates that I am transposing to a range. However they are not transposed as dates, they are transposed as strings.

```
Dim termdates As Variant
termdates = Array(DateSerial(2020,6,20), DateSerial(2021,6,20), DateSerial(2022,6,20))

Range("C1:C3").Formula = Application.Transpose(termdates)
```

How do I convert `range("C1:C3")`to dates? Alternatively is there a better way to copy the dates from `termdates` that does not require an additional conversion?

Thank you in advance

Comment: The code to transpose without losing dateness is at the bottom of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53350351/11683) (you need to transpose manually).

Comment: Thank you, forgive the rookie questions. So if I want to maintain the date format, I need to transpose manually. If I wanted to convert the range of string dates after the fact, what would be the syntax? I have tried using CDate, but I am not getting it to work.

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/299437/52365

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20375233/7204030 this did the trick for me. Thank you